# Messages are lost on dropping and recreating kafka streams using ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have an issue related to recreating streams and tables. if we drop a stream/table  and recreate it with same query only new messages will be there in the corresponding topics even though we've set ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset to earliest in ksql server config. we are having this issue after we implemented the config ksql.streams.processing.guarantee to exactly_once_v2.

I've tried to check query using select command like below. instead of creating stream, we just tried to select records with this query, and the results contains all the messages.

```
SELECT 
    STRUCT( `Id`:= ROWKEY->ID, `RoleId`:= 4) AS ROWKEY,
    BEFORE,
    AFTER,
    OP
FROM STREAM_DATACHANGES_EDITOR
WHERE (AFTER IS NOT NULL AND AFTER->STATUSID IN (1,2)) OR (OP = 'd');
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ksql does not create a unique consumer group for every query. Therefore, deleting any stream and recreating will not reset any previously committed offsets from your source topic. `auto.offset.reset` only applies when no offsets exist.

You'd need to use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` before recreating a stream

Comment: But on each time we drop and recreate, the consumer name will be appended with queryId, so the consumer name will be different and it should start consuming from the beginning .

Comment: "consumer name will be appended with queryId" - Based on what? You are saying it **does** create a unique consumer group for each query? If so, then it should respect `auto.offset.reset`. Regardless, messages are not "lost" until the Kafka topic retention has expired, and there is no reason to recreate any stream/table only to get new events